# tex4ebook for dummies

Tags: tex4ebook

I'm not able to make `tex4ebook` to work with even the simplest document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
this is a test

\end{document}
```

when I run `tex4ebook filename.tex` I get:

> filename.tex:1: unexpected symbol near '\'

What is wrong?

### Some further information

I have installed make4ht into the main texmf tree:

```
~/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/lua/make4ht/
```

then linked the make4ht file into the PATH directory so that it can be invoked.

Now if I try `make4ht filename.tex` I get:

> ~/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht:11: module 'make4ht-lib' not
>   found:
>
> no field package.preload['make4ht-lib']
>   [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-lib'
>   [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-lib'

While if I issue `tex4ebook filename` I get the same result as before.

Comment: do you have current version of `tex4ebook`? your sample compiles fine for me. Could you post here complete terminal output?

Comment: @michal.h21 That already is the complete terminal output. I have just downloaded everything from your github. The same file works fine with htlatex

Comment: it seems there is some problem with your installation then :( do you have `make4ht` installed? do you get the same error with `make4ht filename.tex`?

Comment: @michal.h21 I just noticed that I don't have any make4ht executable even though I installed make4ht following the instructions on git. Where is the make4ht executable located?

Comment: if you are on unix system, try command `ln -s \`kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME\`/scripts/lua/make4ht/make4ht /usr/bin/make4ht`

Comment: update, you shouldn't install it to the main texmf tree, you should use local texmf tree, which is usually `~/texmf`

Comment: I already tried to install in the local tree but the result was the same. As you can see from the update now the system can find the make4ht executable, but can't find the libs.

Comment: did you run `texhash` command to update TeX name database? it is not needed in local texmf, but in system texmf it is

Comment: I tried texhash (I also moved the make4ht directory into the local texmf tree, just to be sure) but still when I run `make4ht filename` I get a `no field package.preload['make4ht-lib']` etc. error.

Comment: @skey: I looks like a load error for some library. Have you tried `ldd make4ht`?

Comment: @skey: I just installed `make4ht` and then `tex4ebook`, then run your MWE -- there were no problems, so I can't reproduce your problems, sorry

Comment: I found what causes the above error. As I just had this error and fixed it. If this was open I can answer and show how to resolve this error `module 'make4ht-lib' not found:` that you got.