# tex4ebook error: unable to convert to number

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, tex4ebook

I tried to run `tex4ebook` on the same MWE of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208061/28685) (actually I tried also with a much more complex source, getting the same problem)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
this is a test

\end{document}
```

with

```
tex4ebook test.tex -format epub3 -shell-escape
```

and I got the following error:

```
tex4ebook:unable to convert to number: -m
```

I just updated with `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` my TexLive 2016 Windows distribution (which updated `tex4ht` among others), and `htlatex` works correctly on my system. For example, running

```
htlatex test.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in,3,next,mouseover" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

produces the expected `xhtml` file.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two formats to pass options to `tex4ebook`, short  and long names. Short options begin with one `-`, while long options begin with `--`. The problem in your case is that you want to use long names, but you start them with just one `-`, so `tex4ebook` tries to recognize them as as short ones.

You should either use

```
tex4ebook  --format epub3 --shell-escape test.tex
```

as long options, or

```
tex4ebook  -sf epub3 test.tex
```

for short options. As you can see, you can collapse multiple short options into one.

Comment: About the double `--` I guess you might want to fix the documentation on CTAN ( http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/tex4ebook/tex4ebook-doc.pdf ), since from that PDF seems that also the full length option version (like `format`) should be called with a single `-`. I guess Tex replaced the double dash with a single longer dash.

Comment: you are right, I've missed that. it is indeed the issue that double hyphen is replaced with dash

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the syntax you are using. Instead of:

```
tex4ebook test.tex -format epub3 -shell-escape
```

please try:

```
tex4ebook --format epub3 -s test.tex
```

The epub will be generated.

Note: The problem is fixed when the last argument is the **filename**.